# Can somebody explain why this program can count the number of digits after decimal point?

Tags: c++

Apparently, this program can count the number of digits after the decimal point. And it works, but I had some hard time understanding it.

What does bool do here exactly?  And what does if(ch=='.') f=true; achieve here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char ch;
    bool f=false;
    int num=0;

    while((ch=getchar())!='\n')
    {
        if(f)
            if(ch>='0' && ch<='9')
                num++;
            else
                break;
        if(ch=='.')
            f=true;
    }
    if(num>0)
        cout<<num<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"false"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It can give the result perfectly. Just curious why it works.

Comment: A very thorough search of the shown code found no existence of any "bool function", only a bool variable. And what " if(ch=='.') f=true;" achieves is exactly what it says: if the `ch` variable is a period, set `f` to `true`. What part of this is unclear to you? If you would like to examine how this logic works, that's what a debugger is for. Your debugger will show you how this program runs, one line at a time, letting you observe its logical flow and all variables as they change. Run this program in a debugger, and see for yourself.

Comment: Let's not downvote the question just because it's from a novice. It's a clear question with a small code snippet, perfect for SO. We were all novices once.

Answer (score 2):

I don't blame you for being confused. It goes to show the importance of good variable names. `f` tracks whether we've seen a `'.'` yet. It should be named something more descriptive such as `haveSeenDecimalPoint`.

```
bool haveSeenDecimalPoint=false;

while((ch=getchar())!='\n')
{
    if(haveSeenDecimalPoint)
        if(ch>='0' && ch<='9')
            num++;
        else
            break;
    if(ch=='.')
        haveSeenDecimalPoint=true;
}
```

It starts out as false, meaning we haven't seen a `.` yet. The first `if` statement is continually false. When we see a `.` then the second `if` statement sets the flag to true. After that, any additional characters will trigger the inner `if`/`else` tests. Any digits after the decimal point trigger `num++`, and as soon as we see a non-digit we `break` out of the loop entirely.

Answer (score 1):

`f` is a **variable** (not a function, although it doesn't have a very descriptive name) of `bool` type that, in this case, marks whether the `.` character has already been encountered. It starts as `false` and switches to `true` once a `.` character is read. That's what the `if (ch == '.') f = true` is for.

Once it has found a `.` character, it will start counting digits. That's what these lines are for:

```cpp
if ('0' <= ch && ch <= '9') num++; // Count a digit character
else break;                        // If not a digit, break the loop
```

After breaking the loop, the rest of the code just prints the number of digits found.

Answer (score 0):

This answer rather should be a comment, but comments do not allow to present more complex code...

[John Kugelman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68587/john-kugelman) already has given an appropriate [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55437022/1312382), but the code can yet be better structured:

```
if(haveSeenDecimalPoint)
// while braces are optional in given case, they still better are placed
// as the following code is pretty complex; you gain better overview
{
    if('0' <= ch && ch <= '9') // optional; ressembles closer mathematical
                               // expression 0 <= ch <= 9
                               // (which cannot be written that way in C++!)
        num++;
    else
        break;
}
// if decimal point HAS been found already, no need to check any further
// so place the else to avoid unnecessary checks (if another period occures, 
// it's already covered by breaking on ch < '0' || ch >= '9')
else if(ch == '.')
{ // due to the newly introduced else: recommendation: if one branch needs 
  // braces, place on all of them – some coding conventions even mandate
  // ALWAYS placing braces
    haveSeenDecimalPoint = true;
}
```

Code without comments:

```
if(haveSeenDecimalPoint)
{
    if('0' <= ch && ch <= '9')
        num++;
    else
        break;
}
else if(ch == '.')
{
    haveSeenDecimalPoint = true;
}
```

Have an eye for the additionally placed spaces, they improve readability, too.

Answer (score 0):

That loop is doing two different things, and uses `f` to keep track of which one it's doing. That's often confusing, and the code should probably be written as two separate loops:

```
// skip until the decimal point
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != '.')
    ; // nothing to do here

// check that we haven't hit the end of the input
if (ch != '\n')
    // count digit characters
    while ((ch = getchar()) >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        ++num;
```

Note that in the last loop there is no explicit check for `'\n'`; that's not needed, because `'\n'` will not be between `'0'` and `'9'`, so getting `'\n'` will end the loop.